# Check external DNS with dd-wrt

Tags: router, dns, dd-wrt, opendns

I'm trying to change the DNS server my router is using to OpenDNS and I'm running dd-wrt, but when I try to check which server I am using by checking the contents of `resolv.conf`, I get

```
search lan
nameserver 192.168.11.1
```

which is probably the local DNS. Is there any alternate way?

Comment: How are you changing it, through the routers web interface? Are you checking the contents of resolv.conf on the router? Did you reboot the router after making the change?

Comment: have you tried the webui? http://www.opennicproject.org/configure-your-dns/how-to-change-dns-servers-in-dd-wrt/

Comment: I'm changing it on the router web interface, with both methods described here: http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/OpenDNS

Comment: I've chosen "apply settings" each time.